# Asset Catalog Launch Image Not Being Used for 4 inch simulator

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, image, asset-catalog

For some reason my 4inch launch image isn't chosen when I reference it programmatically from an asset catalog?  It uses the default launch image for the 3.5.  Any clue?

```
UIColor *image = [[UIColor alloc] initWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"LaunchImage"]];
self.view.backgroundColor = image;
```

Comment: If you try to reference directly to the file does it load the correct one?

Comment: Did you try specifying `LaunchImage-568h`? This is currently required for 4".

Comment: possible duplicate of [Xcode 5 & Asset Catalog: How to reference the LaunchImage?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19107543/xcode-5-asset-catalog-how-to-reference-the-launchimage)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using the launch image asset catalog, I created another with the same images and used that as the background image reference.

```
UIColor *image = [[UIColor alloc] initWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Background"]];
self.view.backgroundColor = image;
```