# Frame error size in IOS8

Tags: uiwebview, ios8

I have some problem when I load a web view inside my app.

Problem appears only with ios8, while in ios7 is ok

this is the code

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
[super viewWillAppear: animated];
[ [ UIApplication sharedApplication ] setStatusBarHidden: YES withAnimation: UIStatusBarAnimationNone ];
webView.scrollView.minimumZoomScale = 1.0;
webView.scrollView.maximumZoomScale = 1.0;
webView.scrollView.bouncesZoom = NO;
webView.scrollView.multipleTouchEnabled = NO;
webView.scrollView.bounces = NO;
webView.mediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction = NO;
webView.allowsInlineMediaPlayback = YES;
webView.scalesPageToFit = YES;
self.view = webView;
webView.dataDetectorTypes = UIDataDetectorTypeNone;

NSURL *url = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"dv/index" withExtension:@"html"];
[ webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL: url ] ];
}
```

and this is the result https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/552704/view.png

Comment: Your code is messy. It includes both YES and NO and YES again for scalesPageToFit.

Comment: What should the result be? And is it the web view's frame that has the wrong size or is it the content in the web view that is sized wrong?

Comment: the result should be a full screen webview. the web view's frame is smaller than the ios7 version and it's located not in the correct position but over the green frame.

Comment: ios8 version [link](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/552704/view.png) iOS7 version [link](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/552704/view2.png)

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in the code that positions the webView (probably a UIWebView), you are probably using `[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size` which has become rotation dependent in iOS 8, see

[Is [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size becoming orientation-dependent in iOS8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24150359/is-uiscreen-mainscreen-bounds-size-becoming-orientation-dependent-in-ios8)