# iOS 8 screen bounds different on device and simulator in landscape orientation

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios8, bounds, uiscreen

I have an app that runs in landscape orientation.  I have used the code below to make it work on iOS 8.  This code works perfectly on the simulator for ALL devices.  However, when I run it on an iPhone 5 device the layout is wrong.  Having read some other questions on here and other places I believed that the screen bounds had been swapped round on iOS 8 when running in landscape mode but it seems that this is not always the case.

```
CGRect screenBound = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
CGSize screenSize = screenBound.size;
if (SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(@"8.0"))
{
    ScreenHeight = screenSize.width;
    ScreenWidth = screenSize.height;
}
else
{
    ScreenHeight = screenSize.height;
    ScreenWidth = screenSize.width;
}
```

Why is the simulator doing something completely different from the device?  Does this only affect iPhone 5 or all iPhones/iPads?  I don't have access to all devices running different iOS versions so was relying on the simulator to provide accurate results.

Is there a more reliable way of implementing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to resolve this myself as below.  This works for all current iPhone/iPad devices running iOS 8 where the app is set to run in landscape mode only.  Not sure why the code I originally posted doesn't work.

```
CGRect screenBound = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
CGSize screenSize = screenBound.size;

if (screenSize.width > screenSize.height)
{
    ScreenHeight = screenSize.width;
    ScreenWidth = screenSize.height;
}
else
{
    ScreenHeight = screenSize.height;
    ScreenWidth = screenSize.width;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an enhancement, not a defect.
For more information, please refer to the following post:
[Is [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size becoming orientation-dependent in iOS8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24150359/is-uiscreen-mainscreen-bounds-size-becoming-orientation-dependent-in-ios8)