# [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size differences between iOS 7 and iOS 8

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, ios7, ios8

UIScreen in iOS 8 is now interface oriented ([Is [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size becoming orientation-dependent in iOS8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24150359/is-uiscreen-mainscreen-bounds-size-becoming-orientation-dependent-in-ios8/25791923#25791923)).

My app runs in landscape mode only — so in iOS 7 and iOS 8 the values for bounds.size.width and bounds.size.height will be switched. In order to support iOS 7 and iOS 8, does this mean that in my code, I need to detect either the version of iOS (or for example assign the larger of the two dimensions to my 'width' variable and the shorter to the 'height' variable)? I should add that I'm creating views programmatically.

Comment: I've had this problem where you are flipping the width and height values for rotations, it sounds like it's made simpler in iOS 8 but it's probably best practice to check the iOS version and if it's <8.0 then flip them as you would before

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you would need to programmatically check the OS version and return the appropriate value. Here's one way to check: [How can we programmatically detect which iOS version is device running on?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7848766/how-can-we-programmatically-detect-which-ios-version-is-device-running-on).

Comment: Thanks. I think rather than detect the version though, I will just calculate which is larger and then assign the width to the larger of the two values.