# Older EAGLView based apps are rendering 25% up and to the left on iPad Air (Landscape)

Tags: ios, ipad, ios8, eaglview

I am getting a very odd anomaly with iOS 8 where my screen is rendered 25% up and to the left... I check all the values coming from bounds etc and all seems correct. My project is based on the old EAGLview code, and I have tried using xib (which USED to work fine) and also tried generating the window myself and subsequent glview myself. I always get the same result. The screen is shifted 25% up to the left (along with the touch area). Its quite baffling. Anyone have any ideas on this?

Comment: BTW the apps all run in landscape mode (and all worked fine pre iOS 8)....

Answer (score 0):

[UIScreen bounds] is now interface-oriented;

I was setting the bounds differently in iOS7 , but now something like this looks like working for me:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    _screenWidth = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width;
    _screenHeight = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height;

}
```

also have a look here if that does not solve the issue:

[Is [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size becoming orientation-dependent in iOS8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24150359/is-uiscreen-mainscreen-bounds-size-becoming-orientation-dependent-in-ios8)