# iOS8 Full Screen View is cut off

Tags: ios, ios7, ios8

In iOS7 I was able to create a full screen view using the following code:

```
- (void)loadView {
    CGSize screenSize = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size;
    CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, screenSize.height, screenSize.width);
    UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame: frame];

    self.view = view;
}
```

When moving to iOS8 this code does not work properly, the screen is cut off on and scaled on the right side, similar to this:

```
---------------   ---------------   
|             |   |         |   |
|     iOS7    |   | iOS8    |   |
| Full Screen |   | Cut Off |   |
|             |   |         |   |
|             |   |         |   |
---------------   ---------------
```

This is affecting all full screen views in my app which are programmatically generated, any ideas here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of:

```
CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, screenSize.height, screenSize.width);
```

You need

```
CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, screenSize.width, screenSize.height);
```

Its:

```
CGRect CGRectMake ( CGFloat x, CGFloat y, CGFloat width, CGFloat height );
```

Comment: This worked thanks!, However any thoughts on why this worked OK in iOS7? I should have noted that the app is landscape mode.

Comment: On iOS UIScreen is now interface oriented, check this for more http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24150359/is-uiscreen-mainscreen-bounds-size-becoming-orientation-dependent-in-ios8