# Different UIScreen bounds returned by iOS7 and iOS8

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios7, ios8

I make application for Deployment target >= 7.1. And i see the "bug"...
Application run in only landscape mode!

Code:

```
CGSize frameSize = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size;
```

In iOS 7 (iPhone 4), returned `CGSize (width=320, height=480)`, but must returned `480x320` (Because run application in landscape mode).
In iOS 8 (iPhone 4S), returned `CGSize (width=480, height=320)` - correct result.

The impression that iOS 7 returned frame without check landscape/portrait mode, and return size for portrait mode.

Thank.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The behavior changed in iOS 8.

Quoting `UIScreen` documentation

> Prior to iOS 8, a screen’s bounds rectangle always reflected the screen dimensions relative to a portrait-up orientation. Rotating the device to a landscape or upside-down orientation did not change the bounds. In iOS 8 and later, a screen’s bounds property takes the interface orientation of the screen into account. This behavior means that the bounds for a device in a portrait orientation may not be the same as the bounds for the device in a landscape orientation. Apps that rely on the screen dimensions can use the object in the fixedCoordinateSpace property as a fixed point of reference for any calculations they must make.

Answer (score 6):

Yes there is change in API for iOS 8.

Yes, it's orientation-dependent in iOS8, not a bug. You could review session 214 from WWDC 2014 for more info: "[View Controller Advancements in iOS 8](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2014/#214)"

Quote from the presentation:

UIScreen is now interface oriented:

```
[UIScreen bounds] now interface-oriented
[UIScreen applicationFrame] now interface-oriented
Status bar frame notifications are interface-oriented
Keyboard frame notifications are interface-oriented
```

Possible duplicate que: [Is [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size becoming orientation-dependent in iOS8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24150359/is-uiscreen-mainscreen-bounds-size-becoming-orientation-dependent-in-ios8)

To achieve your goal, check iOS version and run the code accordingly:

[How can we programmatically detect which iOS version is device running on?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7848766/how-can-we-programmatically-detect-which-ios-version-is-device-running-on)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Shouldn't `-convertRect:fromWindow:nil` continue to do the correct thing? If so then there's no need for the author to write his own little custom conversion code with a version check. Just use the intended built-in method?