# How to detect iPad orientation in iOS8 keyboard extension

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, swift, ios8

Currently I'm using this method to detect the orientation and device:

It works for iPhones, but these's an issue with iPad, that is whatever the orientation is, `[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width`always ==768, and  `[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height` always == 1024. What's wrong with my coding?

```
 +(NSString*)GetOrientation{
    if([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width < [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height){
        NSLog(@"Potrait");
        return @"Potrait";
    }
    else{
        NSLog(@"Landscape");
        return @"Landscape";
    }


}
+(NSString*)GetDeviceAccordingToScreenSize:(UIViewController*)ctrl{
    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice].model isEqualToString:@"iPad"]) {
        int screenWidth = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width;
        if (screenWidth==768) {
            return @"P-iPad";

        }else if(screenWidth==1024){
            return @"L-iPad";

        }else{
        return @"ERROR";
        }
    }else{
        if ([[self GetOrientation] isEqualToString:@"Potrait"]) {
            int screenHeight = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height;
            switch (screenHeight) {
                case 667:{
                    return @"P-iPhone6";
                    break;
                }

                case 736:{
                    return @"P-iPhone6Plus";
                    break;
                }
                case 568:{
                    return @"P-iPhone5";

                }
                default:{
                    return @"P-iPhone4";
                    break;
                }
            }
        }else{
            int screenWidth = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width;
            // float screenHeight = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height;
            switch (screenWidth) {
                case 667:{
                    return @"L-iPhone6";
                    break;
                }

                case 736:{
                    return @"L-iPhone6Plus";
                    break;
                }
                case 568:{

                    return @"L-iPhone5";
                    break;
                }
                default:{
                    return @"L-iPhone4";
                    break;
                }
            }

        }

    }

}
```

By the way, in extension you don't have access to [UIApplication sharedApplication]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use **nativeBounds** instead of bounds to make sure the result doesn't depends on the device orientation of the application while it is being launched.

```
extension UIDevice{
    var detail:String {
        if iPhone {
            if UIScreen.mainScreen().nativeBounds.height == 480 {
                return "iPhone Classic"
            }
            if UIScreen.mainScreen().nativeBounds.height == 960 {
                return "iPhone 4 or 4S"
            }
            if UIScreen.mainScreen().nativeBounds.height == 1136 {
                return "iPhone 5 or 5S or 5C"
            }
            if UIScreen.mainScreen().nativeBounds.height == 1334 {
                return "iPhone 6"
            }
            if UIScreen.mainScreen().nativeBounds.height == 2208 {
                return "iPhone 6+"
            }
        } else if iPad {
            if UIScreen.mainScreen().nativeBounds.height == 1024 {
                return "iPad Classic"
            }
            if UIScreen.mainScreen().nativeBounds.height == 2048 {
                return "iPad Retina"
            }
        } else {
            return "Undefined"
        }

        return "test"
    }
    var iPhone:Bool {
        return UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == .Phone
    }
    var iPad:Bool {
        return UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == .Pad
    }
    var width:CGFloat{
        return UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width
    }  
    var landscape:Bool {
        if iPad && ( width == 1024.0 || width == 2048.0 ) {
            return true
        }
        if iPhone && ( width == 480.0 || width == 960 || width == 1136.0 || width == 1334.0 || width == 2208.0 ) {
            return true
        }
        return false
    }
}
if UIDevice().iPhone {
   println("This device is an iPhone")
}
if UIDevice().iPad {
    println("This device is an iPad")
}
println("Device detail: " + UIDevice().detail )
println("Landscape: " + UIDevice().landscape.description )
```

Comment: Thank you. I solve the problem already. Forgetting to disable size class of the xibs caused the problem. Sorry for wasting your time.

Answer (score 2):

Hum, There was some changes with iOS8,
Now [UIScreen bounds] is interface-oriented
So the width will always be 768.

Reference:

[Is [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size becoming orientation-dependent in iOS8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24150359/is-uiscreen-mainscreen-bounds-size-becoming-orientation-dependent-in-ios8)

Comment: my iPhone and iPad are both running iOS8, why this method works for my iPhone but doesn't work for my iPad? If it doesn't work, what should I use instead?

Comment: It strange that the behavior change from iPad to iPhone. Is it the same iOS 8 version on your iPhone and iPad?

Comment: YES, they are both iOS 8.12

Comment: Thank you, I solved this problem myself. Your answer makes sense but doesn't really solved my problem because this situation is too special. I up voted your answer but I can't accept your answer. Sorry about that. Hope you could understand me.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem myself, hope it will help someone.

I used xib to build the interface of the keyboard. This keyboard run both on iPhone and iPad, so I set up 4 xibs.(iPhone landscape,portrait,iPad landscape, portrait). I forgot to disable the size classes for the iPad ones. After I disabled that, it works perfectly