# [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds Different iOS 8?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad

I just started testing my app on an iPad 2 thats still running iOS 7, because thats what I had lying around. As soon as I open up the app, the main view under the UINavigationController is offset and too small. Heres a picture of what I'm talking about:
[image]

The whole screen should be the light color. I use `[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds` to make the lighter view. I'm compiling this on the iOS 8.2 SDK. After logging the width and height, it seems like they're inverted. Is that how iOS 7 handles things? I think just checking if its running iOS 7 and swapping them will work, but I want to make sure this is the problem. Thanks.

EDIT:
Swapping them worked, but when I go to another view, that view is also rotated, and those are normal views.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

iOS8 bounds are relative to orientation thus a device in landscape will have different bounds from the same one on portrait , in iOS7 this does not happen, the bounds are the same no matter if you are in portrait or landscape

See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24150359/is-uiscreen-mainscreen-bounds-size-becoming-orientation-dependent-in-ios8)

Comment: Even views that don't use the extra view are messed up like this. Is there a way to fix this other than manually going to every view controller and flipping the dimensions?

Comment: See **cbartel** answer (second answer) on the link provided in my answer

Comment: Even using that, when I present something modally, it still only shows half of the view.

Comment: I just bit the bullet and did it for every view controller.