# iphones 5, 6 don't show splash screen

Tags: ios, xcode, splash-screen

I've added splash screen images both to the project folder and to images.xcassets file, however only iPhone 4s (with ios7) shows the splash screen, the others (with ios8) show default launch screen or don't show anything if launchscreen.xib is deleted.

what can cause it for iPhones >= 5 ? the files' names are :
Default@2x.png, Default-568h@2x.png, Default-667h@2x.png, Default-Portrait-736h@3x.png

Comment: you have to just drag and drop image in imageasset > Launchscreen. name doesn't matter when drag and drop. no need to add in project folder.

Comment: yes, all the pictures in images.xcassets file are in Launchimage folder, i've also created Launchscreen folder and added these pictures there, yes with no result

Comment: remove and clean build and try.

Comment: alt+cmd+shift+k cleans the build folder, but this doesn't help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a LaunchImage.xib (via "New > File > User Interface > Launch Screen") and pick this file within the "generals" tab of your target.

Comment: this will show the launchscreen, by the default it contains project name and some other information, however I need the app to show Default image instead

Comment: You can add the image as an UIImageView to the LaunchImage.xib - as far as i know this is the preferred way and suggested by apple. 

please see here
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/MobileHIG/LaunchImages.html

Comment: UIImageView doesn't see LaunchImage set from xcassets so it can't distinguish different images for different iPhone sizes

Comment: Perhaps this will help you (and me to, because I am suffering with this problem too ;) )
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19107543/xcode-5-asset-catalog-how-to-reference-the-launchimage